# How to get the pdf file name with fpdf in PHP?

Tags: php, filenames, fpdf

I have been trying for long to get pdf file name with fpdf, but is not working. This is my code:

```
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
        if (logged_in() === true) {
        if (isset($_POST['do'],$_POST['create_resume'])) {
            $file = addslashes($_POST['create_resume']);
            require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
            setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_US');
            $pdf = new FPDF();
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);

            $file = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $file);

            $pdf->Cell(0, 0, $file);

             //$pdf->Cell(40,10,$_POST['create_resume']);
            $name = $pdf->Output('file.pdf','S');

            $name = pathinfo($name,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // $name = $name['filename'];
           //$name = basename($name);
            echo $name;
```

Comment: you are overriding `$name`

Comment: what do you mean please @masivuye Cokile

Comment: u mean i should remove this part  $name = pathinfo($name,PATHINFO_FILENAME);? @ Masivuye Cokile if that is <> endobj 5 0 obj <> endobj 2 0 obj << /ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB obj << /Producer (FPDF 1.7) /CreationDate (D:20170731121148) >> endobj 7 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Pages 1 0 R >> endobj xref 0 8 0000000000 65535 f 0000000229 00000 n 0000000417 00000 n 0000000009 00000 n 0000000087 00000 n 0000000316 00000 n 0000000521 00000 n 0000000596 00000 n trailer << /Size 8 /Root 7 0 R /Info 6 0 R >> startxref 645 %%EOF

Comment: change `$name` to `$file$name` then echo `$filename`

Comment: Following [these](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163) simple rules could improve your questions a lot. I suggest to follow them. I partially fixed your question now, but I can't be with you every time :-)

Comment: Furthermore, write more about, what doesn't work. Don't make your question look: "Here is my code, debug it", but if you do, you should at least explain, *what* to debug.

Comment: @ Masivuye Cokile this what i get:    **Info 6 0 R >> startxref 645 %%EOF**  please if you can give me example i will be glad thank you